# FTP service for bluetooth implementation

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Does any one know how to implement the FTP server using the OBEX on bluetooth without having root access for android devices which has turned out to be an herculean task for me, please do help any help will be really appreciated. I know that applications are available for FTP on the market but I want to integrate it in the application instead of running that as a background application.